# Click to focus on InfoWindow on Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

Much like any OS where if you click on a window then it brings that window in focus (on top). Is that also possible if you have two overlapping InfoWindow for Google Maps API v3?

I know that there is no `click` listener for `InfoWindow` class as shown in the [official Google Maps API v3 reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#InfoWindow). But there is a `content_changed` listener.

So currently I am thinking of a "hack" would be something like this:

1. The content `div` is clicked (a listener via JavaScript of jQuery)
2. The content `div` will be changed subtly (add an extra invisible character at the end or something)
3. Update the content by `InfoWindow.setContent()`
4. The `content_changed` listener will trigger
5. Set a higher z-index by `InfoWindow.setZIndex()`

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure you need this functionality? The  infowindow's default behavior is that they are not overlap each another and it's gone as soon as you click on the another one. If you show all of them at the same time it could be a real mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to do this... i hope you dont have to many info windows!

But would it not just be simpler to generate an array of all you info windows, then when you div is clicked move that ones z-index higher and the others all lower. Then you just need to have the object name of the info window to call myInfoWindow.setZIndex().

A little simpler.